# Autoincrement with Fresh counters everyday

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

YYYYMMDD-XX

Suppose List Item is created today Its Unique ID should be

```
20150604-01
20150604-02
.....
20150604-99
```

Suppose Item is created Tomorrow Item Unique ID should be

```
20150605-01
20150605-02
.....
20150605-99
```

We are able format date in required way. How do we set set the counters to start again from 01-99 each day. Can someone help on this

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the following things to achieve what you're trying to:

- 1 ItemAdding event receiver which is attached to every list (only those lists apply which use your custom unique ids) [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231563%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- a central place where you store your current id (e.g. SPWeb PropertyBag) so you can increment it whenever a value has been used

public static class PropertyBagExtension
            {

```
public static void AddProperty(this SPWeb web, string key, string value)
{
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    web.Properties[key] = value;
    web.AllProperties[key] = value;
    web.Update();
    web.Properties.Update();
}


public static void RemoveProperty(this SPWeb web, string key)
{
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    web.AllProperties.Remove(key);
    web.Properties[key] = null;
    web.Update();
    web.Properties.Update();
}


public static string GetPropertyValue(this SPWeb web, string key)
{
    if (web.AllProperties.ContainsKey(key))
        return web.AllProperties[key].ToString();

    return null;
}
```

}

- a mechanism which ensures every day, that the id is set to 01 again in the beginning (could be done in the event receiver too)